# iOS reusing custom view objects in grid

Tags: ios, xcode, reload, reusability

I'm using a double nested for loop to add custom UIView objects (around 10, sized 100x100) in a grid format. These custom UIView objects hold a UIButton, UILabel, and another custom UIView object.

When the user refreshes the screen, I want to reload the data and show the latest UIView objects.

When reloading, I have it set up to remove all the old UIView Objects by using removeFromSuperView...and then I add all the new UIView Objects in place.

Is it possible to reuse the old custom UIView object? Do I have to remove all the old custom View Objects before placing the new ones, or is there a cleaner, more efficient away?